# Reference for functorial point of view in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes, group-schemes

I've studied a little bit of scheme theory and category theory. I'd like to understand better what is the functorial point of view in modern algebraic geometry and how it is related to the theory of algebraic groups. What could be a good reference?

Comment: If you want to relate it to algebraic groups, I will recommend Jantzen's book Representations of Algebraic Groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel, Demazure *Groupes algébriques. Tome I: Géométrie algébrique, généralités, groupes commutatifs*. The book presents functorial approach to algebraic geometry and algebraic groups. There is also a shorter version of this book in english.